# S Note is disabled on Samsung Galaxy Note 2

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note-2, s-note

I have a Samsung Galaxy Note 2 (GT-N7100) with Android 4.4.2 (updated). S Note app is good for taking notes, but when I remove the S Pen, this app is not running.

Also, I can not find the app in the Menu. I go to the application manager but see that the program is disabled and can't run it again.

[image: S note is disabled and cant run!]

How can I re-enable it?

Answer (score 0):

> when I remove the S Pen, this app is not running.

Download the latest version of S-Pen And S-Note, then install. And check the results.

Or you can try a factory reset.